# ¿Cómo no permitir eliminar opciones en Select2?

Tags: jquery, select2, html-select

Tengo un select múltiple con el plugin Select2, quiero hacer que ciertas opciones sean fijas, y otras no, por ejemplo, que las opciones **Alaska** y **California** *NO* se puedan eliminar, pero que si la persona selecciona otras, como **Hawaii**, las pueda quitar normalmente.

Quiero saber cómo poder eliminar la ***X*** de algunos tag para evitar que estos se des-seleccionen.

[image: Imagen Select2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edito:**

Acabo de descubrir que existe un atributo `locked` que se parece aún más a lo que quieres hacer y que además quita el icono de borrado del elemento:

http://select2.github.io/select2/#locked-selections

Fiddle de ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/o3s3y42e/4/

**Respuesta original:**

Para evitar que se eliminen puedes jugar con el evento `unselecting` de `select2` y hacer que si el elemento a borrar es "Alaska" o "California" no se siga lanzando el evento.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2({
    tags: true
  }).on("select2:unselecting", function (e) {      
  //Si el elemento seleccionado es Alaska o California lanzamos el preventDefault 
      if (e.params.args.originalEvent.currentTarget.nextSibling.data == "Alaska" || e.params.args.originalEvent.currentTarget.nextSibling.data == "California"){
          e.preventDefault();
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone" data-select2-id="68">
    <option value="AK" data-select2-id="69" selected>Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI" data-select2-id="70">Hawaii</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone" data-select2-id="71">
    <option value="CA" data-select2-id="72" selected>California</option>
    <option value="NV" data-select2-id="73">Nevada</option>
    <option value="OR" data-select2-id="74">Oregon</option>
    <option value="WA" data-select2-id="75">Washington</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Mountain Time Zone" data-select2-id="76">
    <option value="AZ" data-select2-id="77">Arizona</option>
    <option value="CO" data-select2-id="78">Colorado</option>
    <option value="ID" data-select2-id="79">Idaho</option>
    <option value="MT" data-select2-id="80">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE" data-select2-id="81">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NM" data-select2-id="82">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="ND" data-select2-id="83">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="UT" data-select2-id="84">Utah</option>
    <option value="WY" data-select2-id="85">Wyoming</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Ahora mismo si seleccionas el elemento de nuevo en el dropdown se elimina así que habría que darle un pulido pero creo que como punto de partida te puede servir

http://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/m46s7zc9/2/

Comment: Creo que con el `locked` me funcionaria, te coloco el respondido y cualquier cosa te comento, mil gracias

Comment: Parece que todo funciona correctamente, hice este ejemplo https://jsfiddle.net/FabianMontoya97/pch789y6/2/